# Optional routes with dashes

Tags: laravel

I want to create 3 different routes like this:

```
Route::get('schedule',['as'=>'schedule.view','uses'=>'ScheduleController@view']);
Route::get('schedule/{year}-{month}',['as'=>'schedule.view','uses'=>'ScheduleController@view'])
    ->where('year','\d{4}')
    ->where('month','0[1-9]|1[0-2]');

Route::get('schedule/{year}-{month}-{day}',['as'=>'schedule.view','uses'=>'ScheduleController@view'])
    ->where('year','\d{4}')
    ->where('month','0[1-9]|1[0-2]')
    ->where('day','0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]');
```

i.e., you can provide one of:

- no year/month/day
- year & month
- year, month & day

The routes work as-is when I link to them with `route('schedule.view', ['2015','01','01])` but if I omit the parameters it tries linking to `/schedule/{year}-{month}-{day}` (with the braces actually in there!).

Is there a way to get laravel to behave smarter or do I have to give each my routes a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not possible that way because `route()` reads them out of an array indexed by name.
One route per name. So it looks like only the last route will be in that array and the others get overriden.

The function that [returns the route](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L259) does nothing else than:

```php
return isset($this->nameList[$name]) ? $this->nameList[$name] : null;
```

So a different name seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Hrm. I figured it should had errored if I redefined the route name then. I thought maybe it could be clever and consider the number of args. Or maybe I could rewrite the route somehow, like `schedule/{{year}-{month}}?{-{day}}?`. Oh well. This isn't a big deal, thanks!

Comment: Looks like it would make sense to throw an exception when multiple routes are defined with the same name yes. Maybe there is other functionality that actually works with multiple routes per name idk. Defining one route with optional params could be an alternative solution yep.